# Determinant of matrix unchanged under unitary change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Shankars' Principles of Quantum Mechanics pg. 42, it was said that the determinant of a matrix is unchanged under a unitary change of basis.

In other words, if $\Omega$ is an $n\times n$ matrix in some orthonormal basis $|1\rangle,...,|i\rangle,..., |n\rangle$ with matrix elements $\Omega_{ij}=\langle i|\Omega|j\rangle, $ we can perform a change of basis using an unitary opertor $U$:
$$|w_i\rangle=U|i\rangle$$
such that the new basis is $|w_1\rangle,...,|w_i\rangle,...,|w_n\rangle$ and in the new basis $\Omega_{ij}=\langle w_i|\Omega|w_j\rangle$.

How can it be shown that the determinant of a matrix is unchanged under a unitary change of basis?

Comment: The determinant is multiplicative, so conjugaction by any matrix does not change the determinant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $\operatorname{det}(AB)= \operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B) $ for two matrices $A,B$. The determinant of a unitary matrix has (absolute) value $1$. More in general, a unitary matrix does not change the length of a vector.